# Draw2djs recreate image with JSON on desktop application

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization

If i have a web application to design a diagram, then i store/serialize this data as JSON into the database.

I have another c# .net desktop application which would get this JSON data and recreate the image in desktop.

Sample json:

```
 var jsonDocument = 
 [
  {
     "type": "draw2d.shape.basic.Oval",
     "id": "5b4c74b0-96d1-1aa3-7eca-bbeaed5fffd7",
     "x": 237,
     "y": 236,
     "width": 93,
     "height": 38
   },
   {
     "type": "draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle",
     "id": "354fa3b9-a834-0221-2009-abc2d6bd852a",
     "x": 225,
     "y": 97,
     "width": 201,
     "height": 82,
     "radius": 2
   }
 ];
```

The reason is i don't want to get the image in each web request from the desktop as this would speed up and less traffic to the server.

How do i do this? I like draw2djs, but it doesnt matter which js library i use.

Please help.